# Access Query To Assign Bag Numbers

Tags: ms-access

I use Microsoft Access to do a mailsort where by addresses are matched to a sorting office  by postcode and allocated a code (mailsort code).

The data is then exported in mailsort code order for printing. As well as printing letters with the addresses, a mail bag label is also printed so that when the letters have been enclosed into an envelope, they can be put into mail bags (i.e. all the 12345 codes go in the same bag etc).

What I would like to do now is add a bag number to the data. So that all the 12345 coded letters are bag 1, all the 67890 coded letters are bag 2. This will make the bagging of the letters easier.

There is an added complication in that Royal Mail will only accept bags that weigh upto 10kg. Therefore the weight of the letters (which is already inputed into my form) needs to be taken into account. For example if the letters weigh 50g and there are 1000 records with the same code, then there would need to be a new bag number every 200 letters (5 bags for  1000 letters weighing 50g).

I can achieve this by using a VBA loop in Access to go through each record and compare the mailsort code with the previous one. If it is the same then it gets the same bag number unless there have already been enough to fill the 10kg bag.

This however is very slow. It currently takes about 5-10 seconds to do a mailsort on 10000 records however, with my VBA loop it adds about 3 minutes!

Is it possible to get the bag numbers by using a query and therefore speed up the process?

I thought if I could add a 'Sub ID', for each mailsort code (e.g. if the first code has 150 records then these would have a Sub ID of 1 to 150, if the second code has 50 letters then these would have a Sub ID of 1 to 50 etc). I could then use the Sub ID to determine if a given code needs more than one bag by dividing the Sub ID by the maximum number of records (determined by the weight of the letter), rounding it to 0 decimal places and adding 1.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Kind regards
Michael

Comment: When you perform this "mailsort" operation are you writing the information into a temporary table and then exporting that (to CSV, or whatever)? If so, does that temporary table have an AutoNumber primary key field?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes the data is stored in a table with an autonumber primary key.

Comment: Okay, good. Do you already use some looping code to populate the temporary table (which you could tweak to add the new [Sub_ID] values), or would adding the [Sub_ID] be a new step in the process?

Comment: It would be a new step in the process. The table is populated by queries. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be able to accomplish what you need without resorting to looping code.

*(I have assumed that your temporary table is named [mailsort] with an AutoNumber primary key named [ID].)*

To assign the [sub_id] values we can use the good old self-join trick. This query will create a temporary table named [tmpSub_IDs] with the values

```sql
SELECT t1.mailsort_code, t1.ID, COUNT(*) AS sub_id
INTO tmpSub_IDs
FROM 
    mailsort t1
    INNER JOIN
    mailsort t2
        ON t2.mailsort_code = t1.mailsort_code
            AND t2.ID <= t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.mailsort_code, t1.ID
```

and this query will copy those values into the [mailsort] table

```sql
UPDATE 
    mailsort 
    INNER JOIN
    tmpSub_IDs
        ON tmpSub_IDs.ID = mailsort.ID
SET mailsort.sub_id = tmpSub_IDs.sub_id
```

so now our [mailsort] table looks like

```
ID   mailsort_code  sub_id  bag_no
---  -------------  ------  ------
  1          12345       1        
  2          12345       2        
  3          12345       3        
...
450          12345     450
451          23456       1
...
```

Now we need to figure out the number of letters per bag. Say we have the related table [mailsort_codes] containing

```
mailsort_code  weight_g  letters_per_bag
-------------  --------  ---------------
        12345        55                 
        23456        65
```

Each letter for mailsort_code=12345 weighs 55g, and dividing that into 10 kg gives

```
10000 / 55 = 181.81
```

We have to truncate (not round) that, so we can have

```
Int(10000 / 55) = 181
```

letters per bag for that mailsort_code. Let's update that column in [mailsort_codes]

```sql
UPDATE mailsort_codes
SET letters_per_bag = Int(10000 / weight_g)
```

giving us

```
mailsort_code  weight_g  letters_per_bag
-------------  --------  ---------------
        12345        55              181
        23456        65              153
```

Now, to assign the bag numbers we can just divide `(sub_id - 1)` by the `letters_per_bag` and round up to the next highest integer (`Int(x + 1)`)

```sql
UPDATE 
    mailsort
    INNER JOIN
    mailsort_codes
        ON mailsort_codes.mailsort_code = mailsort.mailsort_code
SET mailsort.bag_no = Int(((mailsort.sub_id - 1) / mailsort_codes.letters_per_bag) + 1)
```

and we've got

```
ID   mailsort_code  sub_id  bag_no
---  -------------  ------  ------
  1          12345       1       1
  2          12345       2       1
  3          12345       3       1
...
181          12345     181       1
182          12345     182       2
...
362          12345     362       2
363          12345     363       3
...
450          12345     450       3
451          23456       1       1
...
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. I'll add the code and post back to let you know the outcome. Thank you once again!

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you very much indeed for your detailed and well though-out answer. It work's perfectly!

Comment: @user2863528 You're welcome. Does this approach speed up the process somewhat?